# C++ Preprocessor Delay Expansion issue

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, c-preprocessor

The problem is rather simple, I just cannot pass the second macro expansion, it reports an error on Visual Studio 2013 and 2015, but runs well on GCC and Clang.

```
#include <iostream>

#define KS_MACRO_TAIL(A, ...)  __VA_ARGS__
#define KS_MACRO_DELAY(M, ...) M(__VA_ARGS__)

int main ()
{
    int XX = 1;
    std::cout << KS_MACRO_TAIL (_, XX) << std::endl;
    std::cout << KS_MACRO_DELAY (KS_MACRO_TAIL, _, XX);
}
```

Visual studio generates the following equivalent:

```
int main ()
{
    int XX = 1;
    std::cout << XX << std::endl;
    std::cout << ;
}
```

Where `std::cout << ;` is a syntax error, but the above statement is correct.

Comment: What is the error being reported?

Comment: Works fine with `gcc -E` on gcc 5.4.0 (both lines expand to `XX`), so presumably VS-specific.  The compiler error will depend on the context in which you are using the macro, so please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/38975545/edit) to show how `KS_MACRO_DELAY` is being used, and, as @ScottHunter said, exactly what error is reported.

Answer (score 2):

Adding one extra MACRO definition between the call of KS_MACRO_DELAY and KS_MACRO_TAIL:

```
#define KS_MACRO_TAIL(A, ...)  __VA_ARGS__
#define KS_MACRO_EVAL(...) __VA_ARGS__
#define KS_MACRO_DELAY(X, ...) KS_MACRO_EVAL(X(__VA_ARGS__))
```

Comment: Nice solution indeed. `KS_MACRO_DELAY(KS_MACRO_TAIL, _, XX);` works using this. Nested calls still doesn't compile, though: `KS_MACRO_DELAY(KS_MACRO_DELAY, KS_MACRO_DELAY, KS_MACRO_TAIL, _, XX);` Why?

Answer (score 0):

VS2015 is not good at resolving your macros the way you want it. I suggest using a workaround

```
#define KS_MACRO_DELAY1(M, X) M(X)
#define KS_MACRO_DELAY2(M, X1, X2) M(X1, X2)
#define KS_MACRO_DELAY3(M, X1, X2, X3) M(X1, X2, X3)
#define KS_MACRO_DELAY4(M, X1, X2, X3, X4) M(X1, X2, X3, X4)
// etc.
```

Or you should think hard about a solution that doesn't involve using macros at all.